# as an option is selected from the select menu, populated data to next select menu. I want a button below select menu that can delete the slected data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sel_block").change(function(){
            var blockid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getZone.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {block:blockid},
                dataType: 'json',

                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#sel_zone").empty();

                    if(len == 0){
                        $("#sel_zone").append('<option value="">No Data Found</option>');
                        var block_selected=response[i]['block_selected'];
                        $("#blockid").val(block_selected);
                    } else{
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var id = response[i]['id'];
                            var name = response[i]['name'];
                            if(id==name)
                            {

                                 $("#sel_zone").append('<option value="">No Data Found</option>');
                                }
                            else
                            {
                                 $("#sel_zone").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
                                }
                           /*  if(id==name)
                            {

                                 $("#sel_zone").append('<option value="">No Data Found</option>');
                                 $("#deleteblock").append('<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_block.php?blockid='+id+'" id=delete_block>');
                                }
                            else
                            {
                                 $("#sel_zone").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
                                 $("#deleteblock").append('<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_block.php?blockid='+id+'" id=delete_block>');
                                } */

                            var block_selected = response[i]['block_selected'];
                            $("#blockid").val(block_selected);
                        }
                    }



                }


            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

This brings data to my select menu. Now what m trying to is provide delete button below each dropdown. So that user can delete the selected option.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_block.php?id=<?=something?>" id=delete_block>
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>  Block
</a>
```

is there any way that on select change, i can also change the "id=something" value.. or on change i can store id in some global variable and use it anywhere on php.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1S3v.png)